# Javascript: How to disable a button instantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Attack = attack button.

When I run this code (click on the button), it takes about 1 second to disable the button. How can I set this up to disable instantly? I'm assuming it's because of the 1000 ms timer, but i'm not sure.

```
var disabledStartTimer = setInterval(disabledTimer, 1000);
var start = 0;

function disabledTimer() { 
    if (start > 5){
        clearInterval(disabledStartTimer);
        console.log("disabled timer stopped");
        blitz.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        blitz.disabled = true;
        start++;
    };
}
```

Comment: Can't you just test it with `1000` replaced ?

Comment: What is the purpose of loop?

Comment: Do you want it to stop when *start* is 5? Because how you have it now, it won't stop until start is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's because of the 1000ms timer. if you set it to 10 it will take 10 ms to disable. if you need it to start disabled, move (or copy) the `blitz.disabled = true` code out of the interval callback:

```
var disabledStartTimer = setInterval(disabledTimer, 1000);
var start = 1;  // set to 1 to maintain consistency (i.e. call blitz.disabled = true the same amount of times as the original code.

blitz.disabled = true;

function disabledTimer() { 

    if (start > 5) {
        clearInterval(disabledStartTimer);
        console.log("disabled timer stopped");
        blitz.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        blitz.disabled = true;
        start++;
    }
}
```

if you need to do more complex stuff and this code is just an example, you can wrap your complex statements inside a function and call it from outside and inside the interval:

```
var disabledStartTimer = setInterval(disabledTimer, 1000);
var start = 1; // set to 1 to maintain consistency (i.e. call blitz.disabled = true the same amount of times as the original code.

function disableBlitz() {
    blitz.disabled = true;
}

disableBlitz();

function disabledTimer() { 

    if (start > 5) {
        clearInterval(disabledStartTimer);
        console.log("disabled timer stopped");
        blitz.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        disableBlitz();
        start++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the timer to 0

```
var disabledStartTimer = setInterval(disabledTimer, 0);
```

or simply call

```
disabledTimer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this:

```
var disabledStartTimer = setInterval(disabledTimer, 1000); // 1 sec
```

To this:

```
var disabledStartTimer = setInterval(disabledTimer, 0); // 0 sec
```

As the time is counted here in Milliseconds. You can be sure of this, it really is because of the `setInterval`.

Comment: hehe whoops! sorry about that